# Historical Crossword Puzzle

Tags: crosswords, history

*This is the first question for the new [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #14: History](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/fortnightly-topic-challenge-14-history).*

---

[image: crossword]

**Clues:**

1. A fight near a place which was sung about 159 years later.
2. A great man dies in a city where they can't build towers.
3. A sailor discovers something other than he thought.
4. A man travels around the world in 108 minutes.
5. Trees fall over in Russia.
6. You too ...?

**Instructions:**

- Each clue represents a historical event.
- Each clue generates 2 entries for the crossword:

  - the year of the event represented as a [roman numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)
  - a single word referring to the event, which can be:

    - the name of a place
    - the first or last name of a person
- You must find the correct position for each entry yourself.
- Allowed directions for entries are right and down.
- Only year numbers are relevant for this puzzle. [AD and BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) should be ignored.
- The combined colored fields will provide a clue for the final solution, a historical event that is known by each visitor of this site.

Comment: If I had to guess without doing any actual solving of the crossword, I would think that the final solution is "birthday".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The events (most of them already found by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel)) are:

> The battle of **WATERLOO** in 1815 (**MDCCCXV***)
>  **ALEXANDER** the Great dies in Babylon in 323 BCE (**CCCXXIII**)
>  Christopher **COLUMBUS** discovers America rather than India in 1492 (**MCDXCII**)
>  Yuri **Gagarin** orbits the Earth with Vostok-1 in 1961 (**MCMLXI**)
>  The **TUNGUSKA** event felled trees in Siberia in 1908 (**MCMVIII**)
>  Julius **CAESAR** is murdered (*And you, Brutus?*), in 44 BCE (**XLIV**)

The resulting grid is:

> `.              M C D X I I I                     X`
>  `.                A                     W A T E R L O O`
>  `.                E                         U     I`
>  `.                S           M             N     V`
>  `.                A L E X A N D E R   M     G`
>  `.                R           C       C     U`
>  `.                            C O L U M B U S`
>  `.                      M     C       V     K`
>  `.                      C C C X X I I I     A`
>  `.                      M     V       I`
>  `.                      L             I`
>  `.                      X`
>  `.            G A G A R I N`

And the highlighted cells ...

> ... form another Roman numeral: **DCCLXXVI** or 776 BCE, the year when the first (Ancient) Olympic Games took place.

Comment: I'm conflicted; these seems to be the right answer but @Glorfindel did most of the detective work, I do not know who to endorse. This seems to come up a lot on this site.

Comment: @AvikMohan, my opinion is that this represented more than half of the work remaining, for what that's worth. But I wanted to mention for posterity "in 325 BCE (CCCXXIII)". Your Roman numeral is right, but you have 32-5, instead of 323.

Comment: @AvikMohan I'm sure Glorfindel posted the partial answer assuming that someone else would build off of it.  It makes sense to me that the accepted answer should be the complete one.  Just my opinion, though.  The decision is yours.

Comment: @AvikMohan Yes, that tends to happen when there are partial solutions. In this case, the individual events weren't that hard to figure out, though. I don't mind that Glorfindel's answer gets accepted, but it's a partial solution. If the OP wants to be Salomonic, they can write their own answer from the partial solutions and accept that. The contributors get some upvotes at least.

Comment: @John: Good catch. That 5 is because I can't read my own handwriting, at least when I'm scribbling furiously.

Comment: +1 - @AvikMohan I started writing the answer (and even trying to fill in the crossword - I just didn't manage to finish the upper left corner) knowing that I would not be able to finish it before attending a meeting. I'm not an experienced Puzzling SE user but I've seen this pattern (one or more answers partially solving the puzzle, and another one finishing it) before and I endorse it.

Comment: Hm. Are we sure about the final answer here? I'm not convinced that every visitor to the site would know that there was a set of ancient Olympic Games that are disjoint from today's series of Games.

Comment: Since OP says that events before 1 BC will generate a clue that is the _first_ name of a person, why would #6 be Caesar and not Julius?

Comment: @DooplissForce, Aha! Or even Gaius! :) Kidding aside, that's a valid point.

Comment: @DooplissForce That was my fault, fixed the question.

Comment: @AvikMohan Good thing to realize is that StackExchange is all about getting the best answer to a question. It's not a competition about who did the most work or came first, but simply who wrote useful answers to questions. If you think both answers are useful, upvote both, but from the point that a complete answer is written a partial answer can hardly be considered useful IMHO. Even if the complete answer may be copying 90% of the same thoughts.

Answer (score 19):

Partial answer ...

Clue 1:

> Battle of **Waterloo** (happened in **1815 - MDCCCXV**, the ABBA song is from 1974)

Clue 2 might be:

> related to the [Tower of Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel).

Clue 3:

> Christopher **Columbus** discovered America in **1492 - MCDXCII**, while he thought he discovered a new route to Asia.

Clue 4:

> Yuri **Gagarin** (his Vostok 1 launched in **1961 - MCMLXI**)

Clue 5 could be:

> related to the [Tunguska event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event) in **1908 - MCMVIII**.

Clue 6:

> ["You too, Brutus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_tu,_Brute%3F), which happened in **44 - XLIV** BC.

Comment: You may want to include the Roman numeral representations of the years, too.

Comment: Clue 2 might be Alexander the Great who died in Babylon (323 BC).